# What Are Some Sharepoint Best Practices?

Tags: sharepoint

Hi guys I am new to Sharepoint. Is it a good practice to query the content database tables  through the SQL Server Management studio?

Which things need to be considered for Sharepoint testing? As of now I have considered Authorizations and Performance of Sharepoint portal.

Still there are lot of things need to be considered but since I am new to Sharepoint can anyone please guide me on how we do Sharepoint testing and things to be considered for Sharepoint testing?

Any help really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anoop. That's a lot of questions. Here are the answers: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/?query=sharepoint%20development&ac=3. And, could you please use a better subject line? -1 for that.

Comment: @Anoop: Why don't you split your question into two - one for querying the database and one for SharePoint testing?

Answer (score 4):

Annop, I can answer your first question.  The best practice is to use the Sharepoint API to access the database.  The Sharepoint database is proprietary to Sharepoint, and Microsoft recommends that it not be accessed directly (or at least never written to directly).  The database contains field names like StringField1, StringField2, NumericField1, etc. so composing a meaningful SQL query would be difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Robert...But still we can execute this query to find out the total no of users in portal area


select webs.FullUrl, Webs.Title, 
    COUNT(WebMembers.UserId) As 'Total User'
from Webs INNER JOIN WebMembers 
ON Webs.Id = WebMembers.WebId
Where fullurl NOT like '%sites%' AND 
    fullUrl <> 'MySite' AND fullUrl <> 'personal'
Group BY webs.FullUrl,  Webs.Title
Order By  'Total User' desc

Comment: If it's a simple query and it's read-only, you shouldn't have any problems, but since I didn't write the API I can't guarantee that you won't encounter some undefined behavior.

Comment: The only real downside is that Microsoft can change the database schema and break your query, although admittedly this is unlikely.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply Robert....i just wanted to use content database for testing purpose only(read only) ..still i can take content database backup and restore it on the other server and i can do testing on that database isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, but there are Sharepoint-specific procedures for backing up and restoring a SharePoint database, especially if you are using a farm.

Comment: If you really have to run SQL queries against the SP databases, make sure you use NOLOCK in your SELECT statement.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your second question, the following link contains several resources to help you with Sharepoint testing:

http://jopx.blogspot.com/2009/03/sharepoint-unit-testing.html

Answer (score 2):

here is a link to help unit testing sharepoint with mocking
http://www.typemock.com/sharepointpage.php

Hope it helps